# What size of posts do I need for an 8' by 10' woodshed?

Tags: deck, post, ledger

I need to build a simple fire wood storage shed with roof, size of shed `8 x 10 ft.`. I will use some concrete blocks for footing, and `2x8` for framing. My question is what size of posts I should consider for such shed, `4x4` or `6x6`?

Answer (score 3):

Either will work. They'll both hold up a conventional roof of that size without issue. Your concern is more a matter of diagonal bracing, especially if the posts won't be in the ground.

Comment: I agree but I don’t think I would spend the extra for 6x6 .+

Comment: @isherwood, thanks for comment. Do you mean I'd need diagonal bracing to support roof or the posts or both?

Comment: The sheathing on the roof act as its diagonal bracing. You need to keep the posts upright.

Answer (score 1):

I have built 3 sheds using two 2X4 at each corner ( two were 8' X 12', one was 8' X 16' and 2 stories). I used 2 X 4 on 16" centers and 1/2 " plywood walls. None fell down or blew away. All were set on flat concrete or cement blocks.  The compressive strength of southern pine is about 13,000 psi so using a design value of 5000 psi appears safe. As noted you do need some structure/diagonals for stability for loads from various directions.

Comment: I was under the impression that there are no walls since you normally wouldn't use posts in that case. It's just a roof. Would you still recommend 2x4s?

Comment: I see , just a roof over firewood. Diagonal bracing is going to be more important than post size.